# Vuetify - Change default color for v-text-field type=date icon

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-cli-3

I'm filtering records between two dates, which will show data brought from the backend. Instead of using the conventional way found in Vuetify's [documentation on date pickers](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/date-pickers/) like in the following CodePen:

[Vuetify v-text-field Date Picker on CodePen](https://codepen.io/DigitalDevGuy/pen/eYZPPJx)

I'm only using a `v-text-field type="date"` to make it simpler as you can see in the following code:

**HTML:**

```html
<template>
    <v-layout align-start>
        <v-flex>
            <v-toolbar flat color="grey darken-4">
                <v-toolbar-title>History</v-toolbar-title>
                <v-divider class="mx-4" inset vertical></v-divider>
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                From:&nbsp;
                <v-text-field type="date" class="text-xs-center ml-2 mr-4" v-model="startDate"></v-text-field>
                To:&nbsp;
                <v-text-field type="date" class="text-xs-center ml-2 mr-4" v-model="endDate"></v-text-field>
                <v-btn @click="list()" color="primary" class="ml-2 mb-2">Search</v-btn>
            </v-toolbar>
          </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
</template>
```

**JS:**

```html
<script>
    import axios from 'axios'
    export default {
        data(){
            return{
                startDate:'',
                endDate:''
            }
        },

        created () {
            this.list();
        },

        methods:{
            list(){
                let me=this;
                let header={"Authorization" : "Bearer " + this.$store.state.token};
                let configuration= {headers : header};
                let url='';
                if(!me.startDate || !me.endDate){
                    url='api/Sales/List';
                }
                else{
                    url='api/Sales/SalesHistory/'+me.startDate+'/'+me.endDate;
                }
                axios.get(url,configuration).then(function(response){
                    me.sales=response.data;
                }).catch(function(error){
                    console.log(error);
                }); 
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

It lets me filter records that took place between both dates selected.

[image]

The only issue I've stumbled upon is the fact that when switching to Dark theme, the default black calendar icon that looks like an `append-icon` (which in this case acts as a button) won't switch to white as it does on the example of Vuetify's documentation:

[image]

I found on GitHub that someone [requested](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/5552) for *color props for append prepend icons in v-text-field* to be added (which sounds really convenient indeed), but the request got labeled as *wontfix*, and the given answer seemed poor for what he and I were looking for as well.

If I add an `append-icon="date_range"`, it only adds another icon (color correct) beside the default black calendar icon and it stops the date picker itself from working. I also can't add a `readonly` prop (with the purpose to avoid the user to type in the date, it only fills the text field with numbers when typed, but the year accepts up to 6 characters when it should only be 4) because it also stops the date picker from working too.

What could I do to switch the color of the calendar icon?

Answer (score 2):

Here you go! [codepen link](https://codepen.io/jessicasachs/pen/eYZPPBX?editors=0010)

#### Globally setting dark mode theme

I think you want to do this. Judging by your screenshot, your date modal looks like it is in light mode still... even though you've toggled to "dark" mode. If you don't do this globally, I think you will find yourself marking a lot of individual components as "`dark`" instead of letting the `<v-app>` delegate the theme to them.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  created () {
    this.$vuetify.theme.dark = true
    // oooor, do it based on to the browser's settings
    // this.$vuetify.theme.dark = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme)').media !== 'not all'
  },
})
```

Basically, Vuetify is... opinionated. They have a lot of scss variables and complex styling. You usually have to go through the front door when you want to change variable colors. Especially in dark mode.

#### Custom icon color inside of a v-textfield using slots

If you want to customize a specific icon color for *one single icon* inside of a textfield, you can use the `v-textfield`'s slots (documented [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields/)) and pass in anything you'd like (for example a `v-icon` using the color prop)

When implementing a more custom UX, you can use `this.$vuetify.theme.dark` inside of your component to determine if you should be "light" or "dark"

Answer (score 1):

The icon you're pointing out is *not* created by the `VTextField`. Rather, it's actually [part of the native `<input>`](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/LYNgabz).

If you prefer to continue using `VTextField`'s native `<input>` for the datepicker, there's currently no way to change the color of that icon AFAIK, but you could adjust the icon's background in CSS, using [`::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator`](https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/Styling%20Form%20Controls#Dateinputtype) as the selector, which allows a couple options as a solution.

#### Option 1: Lighten background color of icon

You could lighten the icon's background to gray, which improves the icon visibility in dark mode:

```css
.theme--dark input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

[demo 1](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/ExKdMNZ)

#### Option 2: Change icon image

You could also change the image of the icon to a PNG of a bright icon in dark mode:

```css
.theme--dark input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  background: url(https://img.icons8.com/cotton/64/000000/calendar.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 24px 24px;
}
```

[demo 2](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/yLORwOL)

Answer (score 0):

Just add one property to your text field which is the `dark` prop :

```
  <v-text-field dark type="date" class="text-xs-center ml-2 mr-4" v-model="startDate">
  </v-text-field>
```